# C# gRPC using deadline instead of cancellation token

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm using gRPC in C# and I keep combining two `CancellationToken` and passing it to the gRPC server : 1 is my "global" cancellation token ( Example if the user hit a "cancel" button ), and the second one is to handle my timeout. I saw that gRPC also have a `deadline` option I can provide to each call. I am wondering if I can still simply use the `CancellationToken` on the server ? Is it gonna be cancelled after the deadline is reached ? Or am I supposed to combine it with the deadline variable inside each method called on the server?

This would allow me to do :

```
await client.MethodAsync( parametersHere, 
    cancellationToken: GlobalCancellationToken, 
    deadline: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2) );
```

Which is quite easier to write and read than combining two `CancellationToken` :

```
using var cancelIn5Minutes = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
using var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken, cancelIn5Minutes.Token);
await client.MethodAsync( parametersHere, 
    cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource);
```

Comment: First one will invoke timeout in grpc. The end. Second one can register some actions on cancellation, for example send command to same grpc channel to gracefully stop remote side if it by chanse receives it. Also in second one it is possible to combine nested timeouts into one.

Comment: So the `CancellationToken` on the server isn't gonna be cancelled after the deadline is reached ?

Comment: This is all implementation specific to gRPC. It can send some packet on message level, but I think it just closes TCP connection, without doing so. On server side it will probably be connection timeout, not cancellation.

Comment: The serverCallContext.CancellationToken is going to be cancelled in these cases:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serverCallContext.CancellationToken is going to be cancelled in these cases: 
1. the call was cancelled by the client
2. the deadline has been reached (which actually cancels the call automatically, so it's kind of a subcase of 1.)
3. there was some other kind of error (e.g. network problem).

The serverCallContext.Deadline is there only for "informative" purposes, no need to track it yourself, gRPC will handle tracking the deadline for you.

Comment: Perfect ! this does make a lot more sense since both the client and the server are aware of the deadline. The syntax also becomes a lot more clean like this!

Comment: Any idea how to differentiate cancellation triggered by cancel or deadline from trigger by network issue. I would like to implement custom retry logic when network issue happens.

Comment: @UnderNotic I believe (although it may be an unfounded belief) that you can differentiate the cause from the RpcException returned.